Angular PWA : Blank page on window reload after ng SW version change
Facing below issue with Angular PWA
I have used below lines of code to reload the app when there is a version change in the change. However , after a version change the app shows a blank page and doesnt load
How to fix the blank page issue when a new version is pushed and user is active on the application. If the user refreshes the page, a blank page shows up
    constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate)
     {
       if(this.swUpdate.isEnabled){
         this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(()=>{
         window.location.reload();

        });
        }
     }

Node : 14.21.3
npm 6.14.18
@angular/pwa: '0.1002.1'
@angular/core : 12.2.17
